# how to convert the following query into Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-controller

I have a query that work fine but does not work pagination how to convert into eloquent to apply pagination

```
$projects=DB::select("select * from projects INNER JOIN(select DISTINCT * from (SELECT project_id FROM district_group_project_users where user_id='$id' UNION ALL select id from projects where created_by='$id') as sub ) as sub on sub.project_id=projects.id;");
```

OR is there any other option to add pagination on the following query? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suppose you have Model called DistrictGroupProjectUser & Project .

```php
$subQuery = DistrictGroupProjectUser::select('project_id')
                   ->where('user_id', $id)
                   ->union(Project::select('id')->where('created_by',$id))
                   ->distinct();

$projects = Project::joinSub($subQuery, 'sub', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'sub.projects_id');
            })->paginate(20);
```

Based on laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins)